# Excel VBA userform closes immediately

Tags: vba, excel, userform

I have this peculiar problem with my userform. I have this piece of code in Module1:

```
Sub dostuff()
    frmMyForm.Show False
End Sub

Sub auto() 'rename to Auto_Open in final version
    Call dostuff
    ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
End Sub
```

The problem is that if I run dostuff() directly, everything works fine (i.e. form is displayed, and user can enter data into it etc). However, if I run auto(), the form frmMyForm just flashes on the screen and closes immediately, after which the line ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False is called.

The intention is to create a workbook which will automatically open a form with some input and output fields (planning to rename auto to Auto_Open when everything works), on which the user can do some calculations etc, and after the user closes the form also close the workbook.

NOTE: if I change my code to:

```
Sub Auto_Open()
    frmMyForm.Show False
    ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
End Sub
```

It also fails in the same way (form flashes and then the workbook closes). Apparently there is something wrong with my form, but I can not understand what, since it works perfectly when called directly from dostuff() in code sample 1

Debugging the code reveals that the userform's Initialize-method is called and it completes successfully, but the actual show fails immediately after showing the form on the screen.

It seems that having the false -parameter in the show-method (I added it there to allow users to use other excel workbooks simultaneously) causes the calling method to continue execution, thus calling the ActiveWorkbook.Close immediately. Moving this to UserForm_Terminate solved the problem.

Comment: It seems you have your answer below but shouldn't it be `ThisWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False` ?

Comment: May be, although when the user closes the form and thus causes the Terminate-event to be called, isn't the workbook of which the form is part always active?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out ? I updated from Excel 2010 to the newest Excel version, and I'm having this exact problem, that wasn't there in the vba 7.0 excel 2010 version.

Answer (score 0):

Change `frmMyForm.Show False` to `frmMyForm.Show vbModal`, otherwise the code after the call will be immediately executed which closes the form again. If you Set vbModal, the code won't be executed until you close the form.

Answer (score 0):

Just call the form like this: Remove the `false`.

```
Sub dostuff()
    frmMyForm.Show
End Sub
```

This will open the form as a modal form by default, which means it will wait until you close it.

Comment: I changed it to false on purpose to allow users to edit other workbooks while the form is open (this was a user requirement), so that they can open this workbook (=form), do stuff, leave it in the background and come back to it later when they need without having to reopen the workbook.